# Do insignificant variables result in a specification error?

Tags: econometrics, misspecification, economics, omitted-variable-bias

I am trying to understand omitted variable bais better. I know that it detects irrelevant variables, but are irrelevant variables and insignificant variables synonymous here? If I have a regression with insignificant (p < .05) variables then do I get a specification error?